# Must the topological boundary of an embedded manifold be a set of Lebesgue measure zero? Why is this question closed?

Tags: lebesgue-measure, differential-topology, manifolds-with-boundary

Let $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$
be a bounded connected $\mathcal{C}^1$
embedded k
dimensional manifold (k<n
); i.e., for each x∈X
, there exists an open (in the subspace topology) neighborhood $U_x$
of x
which is diffeomorphic to the unit open ball in $\mathbb{R}^k$
. Must the topological boundary ∂X
of X
be a set (possibly empty, of course) of Lebesgue measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^n$? Equivalently, must cl(X)
be a set of Lebesgue measure zero? If so, how does one prove it?

Comment: This is false even if $n=k=1$. What did you try to solve this problem yourself?

Comment: I have explicitly excluded the case $k=n$.  However, I have edited my question to include connected, although I am not sure this is needed.  In this case, it is certainly holds for $n=1$, as every open set is a countable union of disjoint intervals.

I can easily construct a connected curve which, has, for example boundary a cube in $\mathbb{R}^3$, but it seems to me that no such example can be an embedding.  My intuition, for whatever it is worth, says that the claim is true.  Perhaps some version of the Lebesgue Density Theorem may come into play, but a proof escapes me.

Comment: The claim is false already for $k=1, n=2$ and $X$ diffeomorphic to the real line.

Comment: I don't understand your post.  The real line is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and a  set of Lebesgue measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: I wrote "diffeomorphic" not "equal."

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: To get an example, take an Osgood curve in the plane, bounding a simply-connected open bounded subset $U\subset {\mathbb C}$. Take a Riemann mapping $f: D\to U$, where $D$ is the unit disk. Take a spiral $S$ in $D$, one end of which accumulates at the origin and the other accumulates to the entire unit circle. Now, take $M=f(S)$. This is your example: Diffeomorphic to the real line, boundary has positive 2d Lebesgue measure.

Comment: The curve you constructed is embedded?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert my comments to an answer:

1. Start with an [Osgood curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osgood_curve) $J\subset {\mathbb C}$. (An Osgood curve is a Jordan curve in the plane that has positive 2d Lebesgue measure.) By the Jordan-Schoenflies theorem, $J$ bounds an open topological disk $U\subset {\mathbb C}$.
2. Let $D$ be the open unit disk (centered at the origin) in ${\mathbb C}$. Let $f: D\to U$ be a Riemann mapping (a conformal diffeomorphism).
3. By [Caratheodory's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_(conformal_mapping)), $f$ extends to a homeomorphism between the closures of $D$ and $U$.
4. Now, let $S\subset D$ be a $C^\infty$ spiral in $D$, diffeomorphic to ${\mathbb R}$, such that the closure of $S$ consists of the union of $S$ itself, the unit circle $\partial D$ and the center of $D$.

If you want a concrete equation, consider the polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$ in $D$, where $0\le r<1$, $\theta\in {\mathbb R})$. Take the function
$$
\sigma: {\mathbb R}\to D,
$$
$$
\sigma(\theta)= \left(\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan(\theta) +1, \theta\right).
$$
(Here I am using the principal branch of $\arctan$.)
Then $S$ is the image of $\sigma$.

5. Lastly, take $M=f(S)\subset U$. Then $M$ is a connected 1-dimensional submanifold of the plane and the "topological boundary" (aka the "[frontier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology))") of $M$ contains the Osgood curve $J$. In particular, it has positive 2d Lebesgue measure.

Comment: I find it hard to accept that an Osgood curve has an open  interior, but I guess that is what the Jordan Curve Theorem states.